# Blackberry appworld support device

Tags: blackberry

I've uploaded an app in blackberry app world. Its support from 4.5

Now i have changed some changes in my app. I've added browser field. Its support from 5.0.

My question is,

Is there anyway to upload that,

```
 old app for 4.5 to 5
 new app for 5 to 7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to confirm this with AppWorld support, but my understanding is that folks with older devices will still get the old version and folks with newer devices will get the new version.  You don't have to re-upload the old version, it "just works" that way.  I had a different problem -- I didn't want my old version to still be available for old OS versions once I updated/upgraded to a newer OS and had to actually make a special request to have the older versions deactivated.

Comment: u r correct. But second point, i dont want. Older version will active in old os.